# Java: serialize / deserialize failed because of `ClassNotFoundException`

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, serialversionuid

I have a `Pilot` class, and an instance of that class: `bobThePilot`.

I serialize `bobThePilot` to a `String` and copy that to my my hard disk. Then I create a new project and recreate the `Pilot` class (exactly identical as before)....

And then I create `newBobThePilot` in this new project by de-serializing the String which I got from my disk. But it fails. Everybody said it was because of something named `serialVersionUID`.

Is it possible to do that (serialize and deserialize in different classes (although exactly identical class)? If so, how?

Thanks.

### Morals:

1. add serialVersionUID attribute to our serialized class Example:
       `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`
2. `implements serializable` to all classes which related to our serialized class

Comment: Why would you recreate a class instead of reusing the one you already have? Anyway, the class is probably not *exactly* the same. Post the source code of both classes, from the package statement to the last line. Also, post the stack trace of the exception you got, and the code used to serialize/deserialize. Serializing to a String is dubious: serialization produces bytes.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: Show us the error (stack trace)

Comment: Your second 'moral' isn't correct. You can extend your classes as much as you like. The mistake was to serialize one class and expect to be able to deserialize as another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't put a serial version id,  the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class. Even though the classes are identical, different versions of the JDK can create different serialversionuids.

Comment: The Java compiler does not 'create one for you'. A default value is computed *at runtime* if the field isn't present. Your final sentence is therefore incorrect as well.

Comment: so when i add the attribute
"**private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;**"
in both (new and old project) Pilot class it would be able?
but that still unable

Comment: oh great, my fault is i **extends** my **Pilot** class.

Answer (score 0):

> But it fails.

Fails how?

> Everybody said it was because of something named serialVersionUID.

Not unless the error message said so. Mor likely it was because of your original error of using String as a container for binary data. It isn't. Just write the actual bytes, don't round-trip them via String.

> Is it possible to do that (serialize and deserialize in different classes

No.